# iPhone backup data overwritten by mistake

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

I was updating my iPhone to iOS 7 and in the process I took a backup of my phone. After installing iOS 7 on my iPhone, I connected it to iTunes and instead of pressing Restore from backup, I pressed Backup and iTunes saved the backup of my restored iPhone, overwriting my original backup data.

The newer backup I have now is of my blank restored iPhone and I don't have a backup in iCloud either. Is there a way of retrieving the backup that I did before updating my software?

Comment: Is there a software that can help me retrieve

Comment: Hey MK could you tell me more about the time machine that you have mentioned that could help me get my data back

Comment: [Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427) would keep backup copies of all files on a Mac where iTunes were installed. You can't use it unless you set it up once (it's a one click operation for most people). If you are on Windows, you might need to ask on SuperUser.com what backup options might exist for your PC / Windows based iTunes setup.

Answer (score 2):

With iTunes backups, there is *only one backup (the latest) maintained per device at any point in time*. Since you have overwritten the older backup with a new one from the fresh install, it's possible to recover only if you have a copy of the backup folder made before the install through the built-in [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht1427) backup system on OS X (if you have a Mac) or any other solution.

Here are the iTunes backup folder locations on different operating systems:
OS X - `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`
Windows (XP, Vista and 7) -  `%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\`

Since you do not have iCloud backups, you're completely out of luck if you didn't have backups of the iTunes backups. If you do back up your computer, simply restore the folder where iTunes stores iOS backups (after making sure you have a current backup for other devices if needed) and you can restore your iPhone from an older backup.

For more information, see these answers to similar questions - they provide details as well as recommendations for the future:
[Restoring an OLD iPhone backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104865/31743)
[Recover iPad Safari bookmarks overwritten by iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101085/31743)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PC, you can play around with Windows Restore and restore your computer to an earlier point. This should put the old iTunes backup in place [unless I am mistaken].